# Listing the Contents of a Section and Page Numbers Underneath the Section Title

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, titlesec, minitoc, etoc

I am currently using the following code to produce a document with a specific style of section title.

```
     \documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{report}
     \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
     \usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
     \usepackage{xhfill}
     \usepackage{varwidth}
     \usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

     \newcommand\Ruled{%
     \titleformat{\section}
     {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}
     {\begin{varwidth}{.7\linewidth}\raggedright##1\end{varwidth}~ \{xrfill[0.3ex]{1.5pt}}
     }

     \begin{document}

     \Ruled
     \section{Section 1.1}
     \lipsum[4]

     \end{document}
```

I would appreciate it if someone could provide a the code to produce the following output
[image]
where the numbers on the far right are page numbers for the relevant subsections. The bottom image shows what I would like to happen if a title for a particular section is too large to fit on one line. The style in
[section format and style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45423/section-format-and-style) is similar to the one I am looking for, however I cannot see a way of getting rid of the dots when using minitoc. I would appreciate a quick response, as I would like to use the layout in an upcoming project.

Comment: While you may need to work on the format, I believe the `minitoc` package does this sort of function.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3001/list-sections-of-chapter-at-beginning-of-that-chapter

Comment: This doesn't seem to be exactly the right style I'm looking for. This seems to deal with sections, rather than subsections, and as you say, the format is different. I'd rather someone provided a code that gives a look closer to that I requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fit to your intended output, as I can see from [section format and style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45423/section-format-and-style):

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\usepackage{color}

\usepackage[undotted]{minitoc}
\setlength{\mtcindent}{-1.3cm}
\renewcommand{\mtctitle}{\colorbox{cyan}{Contents}}
\renewcommand{\mtcSSfont}{\footnotesize\bf}


\makeatletter

\def\section{%
     \if@noskipsec \leavevmode \fi
     \par
     \addvspace{2ex}%
     \@afterindentfalse
     \secdef\@mysec\@smysec}

\def\@mysec[#1]#2{%
    \refstepcounter{section}%   
    \bigskip 

\noindent{\vline  \@height 0.5ex \@width\linewidth}%   )%%% 
    %                                                  )%%% Code to replace to obtain a double horizontal (==) line 
\hspace{-1\linewidth}%                                 )%%%
    %
\colorbox{white}{\normalfont\bfseries\large Section \thesection} 

\noindent
    %
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}\raggedright\bfseries\bigskip#2\end{minipage}%
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.62\linewidth}\minitoc\end{minipage}%

\nobreak
\vskip 3ex
\@afterheading}

\begin{document}

\dominitoc
\nomtcrule

\chapter{1}

\section{Differentiation and integration}

\subsection{Introduction and motivation}

\subsection{Basic definitions}


\subsection{Worked exercises}

\subsection{Homework exercises}


\end{document}
```

However:

(A) setting a background colour of the "Contents" gives an error in compiling (for that reason the entry is commented, see above);

(B) the horizontal line is a little below the one of your intended output.

Given that you asked for a quick reply, I managed to prepare this working solution, and then hopefully yourself or someone else will fix these two little issues.

Edit: To add a double horizontal (==) line instead of the thick solid line after the "Section 1.1", as requested, replace the relative lines with the following code:

```
    \noindent{\rule{\textwidth}{.4pt}\\[\dimexpr-\baselineskip+1mm+2pt]
           \rule{\textwidth}{.4pt}
           }%
%
           \hspace{-1.015\linewidth}%
```

Comment: That would work very nicely. I was wondering if it is possible to improve aesthetics by adding a double horizontal (==) line instead of the thick solid line after the "Section 1.1"?

Comment: I updated the answer adding your request

Comment: Do you know how I would go about altering the vertical space between the "Contents" title and the first subsection title?

Comment: add this line to the preamble \mtcsetfeature{minitoc}{open}{\vspace{1cm}}, where 1cm is the space that you want.